# Nagios Core Error Unable to get process status

Tags: nagios

I'm having issue with Nagios Core Version 4.1.1

I believe it has something to do with httpd, the reason I say so is when I perform

service nagios stop, I still get error message like

**Unable to get process status**

I checked nagios.log and access_log and error_log but nothing obvious to pin point.

Is it because of permissions on directories?

```
[root@puppet nagios]# pwd
/etc/nagios
[root@puppet nagios]# ls -ld .
drwxrwxr-x. 5 root root 4096 Jun 10 22:42 .
[root@puppet nagios]# ls -alrth
total 92K
-rw-r-----.   1 root apache   27 Nov 25  2017 passwd
-rw-rw-r--.   1 root root    44K Nov 25  2017 nagios.cfg
-rw-rw-r--.   1 root root    13K Nov 25  2017 cgi.cfg
drwxr-x---.   2 root nagios 4.0K Jun 10 16:46 private
drwxr-x---.   2 root nagios 4.0K Jun 10 21:52 conf.d
drwxr-x---.   2 root nagios 4.0K Jun 10 22:41 objects
drwxrwxr-x.   5 root root   4.0K Jun 10 22:42 .
drwxr-xr-x. 127 root root    12K Jun 10 23:00 ..
[root@puppet nagios]#
```

Users and permissions also looks okay to me:

```
[root@puppet nagios]# id nagios
uid=495(nagios) gid=492(nagios) groups=492(nagios),48(apache),501(nagcmd)
[root@puppet nagios]# id apache
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache),501(nagcmd)
[root@puppet nagios]# id nagcmd
id: nagcmd: No such user
[root@puppet nagios]# cat /etc/group|grep nagcmd
nagcmd:x:501:apache,nagios
[root@puppet nagios]#
```

httpd.conf configuration:

```
#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
```

Anything I am missing to check?

Comment: Are you using systemd or init.d?

Comment: How do I differentiate between the two? I believe I use systemd, the reason being I restart Nagios using 
service nagios restart

Comment: if you are using systemd then look at `/var/log/messages`. Maybe you see some hint why you have problem.